# SQL Snowflake - Compare 2 dates in one table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datediff

I have the following table

```
card id | txn id | date | legit
 xys       txq      Mar.1  1
 xys       txs      Mar.8  0
 xys       txt      Mar.12 0
 xyb       txl      Mar.13 0
 xyb       txp      Mar.14 1
```

I want to be able to compare the date between the first record and any future records for that card id where that future record's legit = 0, and if the first record is within 10 days, show that record. (note this would also need to include the first record if legit = 0).

If there is a better way to think about this problem, I'm all ears. I'm pretty sure [dateddiff](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/datediff.html) will come in use here but I'm not sure how to make the comparison between the 1st record and any future record.

Example output would be:

```
card id | txn id | date | legit
xys       txs      Mar.8  0
xyb       txl     Mar.13  0
```

`WHERE 
legit = 0
...`

Comment: If the first record is within 10 days of what??  Are you comparing to a current_date() or the max date of that card_id?

Comment: No what it should be is if a record with legit = 0 is within 10 days of the first record, then show that result.

Comment: So, you want the first legit=0 record if it's within 10 days of the first record?  But it also could be the first record, if the first record is legit=0?

Comment: That is correct!

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more efficient way to do this, but I think this gets you what you are asking for:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES 
          ('xys','txq','2020-03-01'::DATE,1),
          ('xys','txs','2020-03-08'::DATE,0),
          ('xys','txt','2020-03-12'::DATE,0),
          ('xyb','txl','2020-03-13'::DATE,0),
          ('xyb','txp','2020-03-14'::DATE,1)) as y (card_id, txn_id, date_, legit)
    )
SELECT card_id,
    CASE WHEN legit = 0 THEN txn_id
         WHEN DATEDIFF('d',date_next,date_) <= 10 THEN txn_id_next
         ELSE txn_id END as txn_id,
    CASE WHEN legit = 0 THEN date_
         WHEN DATEDIFF('d',date_next,date_) <= 10 THEN date_next
         ELSE date_ END as date_,   
    CASE WHEN legit = 0 THEN legit
         WHEN DATEDIFF('d',date_next,date_) <= 10 THEN legit_next
         ELSE legit END as legit
FROM (
  SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY card_id ORDER BY date_) as row_num,
      LEAD(txn_id) OVER (PARTITION BY card_id ORDER BY date_) as txn_id_next,
      LEAD(date_) OVER (PARTITION BY card_id ORDER BY date_) as date_next,
      LEAD(legit) OVER (PARTITION BY card_id ORDER BY date_) as legit_next
  FROM x
  QUALIFY row_num = 1
  );
```

This first gets the first record and the "next record" and moves them to a single line, and then the `CASE` statements determine whether to use the first record or the "next" record based on the rules that I think you specified.

Comment: Thank you Mike, the above appears to work in Snowflake. I am having a slight issue though where  legit = 1 records are appearing as well in my actual query. Not sure why, I believe it may be because this record was joined from another table?

Comment: My results are also indicating it's not capturing all cases either

Comment: Wouldn't you want legit=1 records if they were the first record and there wasn't another record within 10 days?

Comment: Ah, no I only want those txn_ids that are legit =0 and within 10 days of the first transaction (which could be legit =0 or legit = 1). Does that make sense?

Comment: What do you want if the first transaction is legit=1 and there are no transactions within the last 10 days?  Nothing?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That is correct! No records should show for that card id.

Comment: Ok, last question, as this is more complex than I originally thought.  What if there are 2 records within 10 days of the first record (the next is legit=1 and the 3rd is legit=0)?  Do you want the 3rd record?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to compare the date between the first record and any future records for that card id where that future record's legit = 0, and if the first record is within 10 days, show that record.

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, min(date) over (partition by cardid) as min_date
      from t
     ) t
where legit = 0 and date < min_date + interval '10 day';
```

Comment: I don't think one works for what the OP was asking, though.  In yours, the output has to be `legit=1`, but in neither of the records being output does legit=1.

Comment: Thank you for your help @GordonLinoff, unfortunately this doesn't achieve my desired result. Apologies if I've explained unclearly. Please see my comment to Mike above.

Comment: @JCG . . . This answers the question that you appear to be asking.